# Validation event for asp net client side validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I wonder if there's a way to hookup a custom function to asp net client-side validation event, so every time validation is fired by any control I can make some magic on client-side UI

I'm looking for a general approach to intercept page onvalidating event without setting it on every control that causes a postback

Thank you guys

**Edit:**

I ended up with this function: (thanks to @Kirk)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if (typeof Page_Validators != 'undefined') {
            var errors = '';
            $.each(Page_Validators, function () {
                if (!this.isvalid) {
                    errors += this.errormessage + '\r\n';
                }
            });
            if (errors.length > 0) {
                Alert(errors);
            }
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Have you tried in Ajax Update panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something along the lines of this you can place an OnClientClick event on the submit button or just the general form submission event.

Then you can use the `Client Validation Object Model` with the validator controls. This actually allows you to verify each of the validation controls you've setup. There are a couple of values you can check against from the client relating to the page, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0.aspx#ClientSideValidation_ClientValidationObjectModel.

You reference each control with `isvalid` property. For example

```
<asp:Label id="lblZip" runat="server" Text="Zip Code:" />
<asp:TextBox id="txtZip" runat="server" /></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="valZip" runat="server"
   ControlToValidate="txtZip"
   ErrorMessage="Invalid Zip Code" 
   ValidationExpression="[0-9]{5}" />

<script language=javascript>
// Call this function to do something
function txtZipOnChange() {
   // Do nothing if client validation is not active
   if (typeof(Page_Validators) == "undefined")  return;
       // Change the color of the label
       lblZip.style.color = valZip.isvalid ? "Black" : "Red";
}
</script>
```

You can also get an array of the validators on the page with the client function `Page_Validators`. There are a few more functions you can use.

Also you may use the `ValidatorValidate(val)` client function to force a check of each one indivually as well as `ValidatorEnable(val, enable)` to enable or disable validators as your logic demands.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside for a bit more detail.

Hopefully this gets you where you need to go. If not, feel free to ask.

**Previous Comment**
You can use an `onClientClick` and attach a JavaScript function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ytf5t7k.aspx

If you want to use jQuery, you can use `ClientIDMode` you are able easier to figure out control IDs.

Take a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx.

Comment: That's an aproach I could use but I'd need to set t on every control causing postback, I forgot to request for a general approach, please take a look at my question edits and thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if you need any additional clarification on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you man, I think form submit event is what I need, I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: Happy to help. If you can mark this as the answer I'd appreciate it. I'm new here and need all the reputation I can get to try to post and vote on things at this place.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Page_Validators is an array of validation controls in the page. 
if (Page_Validators != undefined && Page_Validators != null) 
{ 
    //Looping through the whole validation collection. 
    for(var i=0; i<Page_Validators.length; i++) 
    { 
        ValidatorEnable(Page_Validators[i]); 
        //if condition to check whether the validation was successfull or not. 
        if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) 
        { 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
}

//if condition to check whether the page was validated successfully. 
if(Page_IsValid) 
{ 
    alert('Success'); 
} 
else 
{ 
    alert('Failure'); 
}
```

Note the very last code example at the bottom of [this page](http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/04/calling-validator-controls-from.html).

Comment: Instead of posting a link a website, please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.