# Why ValidatorValidate() validates all the RequiredFieldValidator controls on the page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, validation-controls

In following code Why `ValidatorValidate(v)` validates all the `RequiredFieldValidator` controls on the page? It should execute only `RequiredFieldValidator1` not `RequiredFieldValidator2`. 
 Here is code.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check() {

            var v = document.getElementById("<%=RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID%>");
            ValidatorValidate(v);

        }
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="check()" Text="Check" />

        </div>

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to return something from check(), otherwise, it's running it, and then passing through and doing the normal page validation.

After calling ValidatorValidate(), you can check if the validator isvalid

```
function check() {

        var v = document.getElementById("<%=RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID%>");
        ValidatorValidate(v);
if (v.isvalid)
     return true;
else
     return false;
}
```

You did have an extra } in there as well.

You also need to throw in a return for the OnClientClick

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return check()" Text="Check" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because once you click the Button, it causes validation of all of them on postback. You'll need to group them by `ValidationGroup` or use `return false;` from `check()` to stop the postback.

Alternatively you could also replace the `RequiredFieldValidator` with `CustomValidator` and do conditional checks based on your needs.

If you REALLY want to do client side validator handling, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0.aspx#ClientSideValidation_ClientValidationObjectModel

This page has details on **Client Validation Object Model** which has a few JavaScript functions to handle conditional evaluation. Check out [Validation event for asp net client side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382849/validation-event-for-asp-net-client-side-validation) for an example of what one person was doing along these lines.

What are you trying to do specifically? Someone can probably help you get the correct setup.

Answer (score 2):

Your `script` is malformed.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function check() {
             var v = document.getElementById("<%=RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID%>");
             ValidatorValidate(v);
         }
   </script>    
</head>
```

In your version you are getting a javascript error that the function `check` is not defined.

The second validator gets also triggered because Validator always are triggered before postback and your function `check` is called on a submit-button. Both validators would validate anyway even without your explicit call on `ValidatorValidate`.

If you don't want to postback onclick, use a HtmlButton instead:

```
<input type="button" onclick="check()" value="Check" />
```