# check only one RequiredFieldValidator using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have Multi RequiredFieldValidators in my Page
I want to check validate of one of them using Javascript Function
can any one help me

Comment: Your question is not clear, What are you trying to do ? enable/disable validation controls ? OR Check validity of controls via JavaScript ???

Comment: @yogi : Check validity of controls via JavaScript

Comment: Means you want to validate a control via JavaScript, If it is so you can use CustomValidator control and write your JavaScript function and provide that function to CustomValidator's ClientValidationFunction. See this http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_customvalidator.asp property.

Comment: NO mr.@yogi ,
I have textbox that validate with RequiredFieldValidator , and i want to check if it validate before write some Javascript code , but without check all page validate

Comment: Hope this will help

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640426/why-validatorvalidate-validates-all-the-requiredfieldvalidator-controls-on-the][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640426/why-validatorvalidate-validates-all-the-requiredfieldvalidator-controls-on-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your javascript code:

```
for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {

                if (Page_Validators[i].Errormessage=="your Error message") {
                    //your code...
                }
            }
```

using above code you can differentiate on the basis of your error message.

Or you can try this, but I am not sure if it work or not:

```
function abc(id){
    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {

                    if (Page_Validators[i]==id) {
                        //your code...
                    }
                }
}
```

in above code **'id' is the clientid** of your particular validator, I am trying to check if two validators are same or not or you can check there equality using any of their unique property to reach your particular validator.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `validationgroup` on you validator and button submit

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup(v=vs.80)

Comment: sorry its not i need,
I have textbox that validate with RequiredFieldValidator , and i want to check if it validate before write some Javascript code , but without check all page validate

Comment: In this case you use validationgroup he permits you to separate your validations and not valid all datas

Comment: ok but i need to check the RequiredFieldValidator validation with javascript to do somthing with javascript if it valid

Comment: for your case i recommend you to use CustomValidator because your logic is not adapted to RequiredFieldValidator