# Change associated textbox color with jquery on client validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I want to use jquery to select an associated element's parent that is required and change the css class.

I need to add a css class "error" to the parent div of the span for the required field. (This will color the textbox according to my css).

I have the following html markup that gets initially generated by my aspx page:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label>Your name</label>
  <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtName" type="text" maxlength="100" id="MainContent_txtName">
  <span data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_txtName" data-val-errormessage="Your name is required" data-val-display="Dynamic" id="MainContent_txtNameRequired" class="error" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="" style="display:none;">This field is required</span>
</div>
```

After "client validation" the span gets changed to:

```
<span data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_txtName" data-val-errormessage="Your name is required" data-val-display="Dynamic" id="MainContent_txtNameRequired" class="error" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="" style="display: inline;">This field is required</span>
```

And after a server postback the span is actually:

```
<span data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_txtName" data-val-errormessage="Your name is required" data-val-display="Dynamic" data-val-isvalid="False" id="MainContent_txtNameRequired" class="error" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="">This field is required</span>
```

I would like to use one javascript function that does not require an onclick function on each button where this would be used. I want to reuse the same function on many pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't find an answer specifically based on how to do this based on the span and data elements, instead an hour or so later I found another question that helped me come up with this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function () {
            if (typeof Page_Validators != 'undefined') {
                var errors = '';
                $.each(Page_Validators, function () {
                    if (!this.isvalid) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass("error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

link: [Validation event for asp net client side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382849/validation-event-for-asp-net-client-side-validation)